# HTML select refreshes page when I submit form

Tags: jquery, html, select, refresh

I have a simple form with some input fields and a dropdown list ().
I use 'return false' with jQuery to avoid the page to refresh after I submit the form and this works like it should.

However, with the 'select' html in the form it does refresh the page and this is not what I want.
Does anybody have an idea on how to avoid the page refresh when the 'select' element is in the form?

Comment: Which platform are you using, and does the select have an onchange event?  Are you getting any JavaScript errors in the console?

Comment: I'm on a Mac with OSX10.6.4, there is no javascript bound to the element and I'm not getting any errors in the console

Comment: Could you post your code?  This sounds like something simple, but it is unclear what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It got fixed in the meanwhile. The template which contained a form was rendered in another form which caused a reload of the page.